# How to detect direction of HorizontalDrag in WP7 XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, gestures, windows-phone-7.1

Like mentioned what is the best way of detecting in which direction the user is dragging horizontally. I'm trying to create a camera class that responds to this gesture but am having problems determining which direction they are dragging. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admittedly I haven't tested this, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.gesturesample_members.aspx) suggests that you should check the value of `GestureSample.Delta.X`, which should be negative for a left movement, and positive for a rightwards one.

Because the delta is only for that particular gesture *sample* (not the overall gesture), you may need to accumulate it, and only trigger your drag action if the accumulated value is above some threshold (possibly upon receiving a `DragComplete`).